# Mechanical engineering, Please help me finding the torque and answering other doubts too

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, automotive-engineering, torque

Below I attached two BLDC motor commonly used for skate boards, I am confused with the calculation of stall torque for these two motors,What i need to know,

1. What is the maximum weight lifting capacity in the condition fig 1 and 2(x and y in kg)?
2. Is maximum lifting capacity is just below stall torque?
3. In figure 1 and 2 they mention torque as 1-2N in yellow motor and 1-2N/N in red motor what they are?Is it a mistake?
4. In red motor speed is RPN is it a typing mistake?[image]

Comment: Yes, I think the N and N/N are both errors, as each should say Nm. Likewise "RPN" should read "rpm"

Comment: any solution for 1 and 2 questions?

Comment: Suggest you choose a different supplier that will give you the necessary info.

Comment: What other details needed than given here to know the weight lifting capacity of a motor?

Comment: At what speed do you want to lift your weight? How quickly do you need to accelerate to that speed from a standstill?

Comment: 300meter per hour,ie 0.083m per second,30kg lets assume it.

Comment: And the acceleration?

Comment: want to play how many typos can we find in the figure.. stop shopping ebay or wherever you found this crap.